# SVN use for Team development with Intel XDK New

Tags: svn, intel, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I have installed Intel XDK New by registering with my email ID. I work with a fellow developer on the same project, It seems I can grant access to my team mate email in http://appcenter.html5tools-software.intel.com/

Does it share code on cloud to him? How can we make use SVN for team development? I know that Intel XDK NEW does not have SVN features on its own.

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The cloud part of the new XDK only provides build and debug services (push to the cloud to build and facilitating weinre via the Test tab). With the old XDK it would also populate your local directory with projects that had been pushed to the cloud, but this is not the case with the new XDK.

The XDK today does not include any revision control services. However, since your project files are all local to your dev system, you can use whatever remote version control and/or sharing service you like to share source files. For example, you could use dropbox or something similar to share your sources directly or you could use a git repo on github to share them. It's up to you to manage that process.